Are there ways to assist Gurobi in finding good solutions?
I have a variant of a vehicle routing problem encoded as a MILP. I am getting OK, but not great solutions with Gurobi. My main issue is there's a lot of natural ways to improve the solutions found that I suppose are getting lost in the constraints.
Say my objective function is $f(\cdot):X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I also have my natural optimizer $g(\cdot): X \rightarrow X$ that satisfies $g(g(x))=g(x)$ and $\forall x\, f(g(x)) \leq f(x)$.
Is there any easy way to help Gurobi (or any other optimizer) by giving it access to $g$?
My attempts so far is to apply $g(\cdot)$ at the end, and every so often take the best current $x$ and then do a warm restart with $g(x)$ but I can't help but feel there will be a better way to make use of $g$.

Can you tell us more specifically about g(x) and its properties? If x is feasible, is g(x) also feasible?  Is f(g(x)) linear (affine). What "type" of problem would it be if f(g(x)) were the objective function? I'll leave someone else to address callbacks.

Thanks, g(.) will preserve feasibility. f(g(x)) is not linear which is why I was reluctant to make it the objective. It might also be somewhat inefficient so using it constantly might be an issue but only as a helping hand should be fine.
g(x) basically looks at the set of routes in x and tidies them up. The formulation allows the vehicles stop at intermediate nodes which is sometimes important. g() will look at all the set of routes and then remove all unimportant stops and perhaps some other little changes that should improve the routes.

You can use a callback to get each new Gurobi solution $x$ and tell Gurobi about your improved solution $g(x)$. This article illustrates it in the context of the Python API. (It might be a bit, um, terse.)

I would suggest watching Faster MIPs Using Custom Heuristics by Gurobi's Greg Glockner.
